# SQL Query to SQL DataSource

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have created this query but I dont know how to bind it to a sqldatasource so I can create a datalist, can someone please help me?

```
    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    If Session("Email") <> "" Then
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Name From [Games] Where Platform = @Platform AND Genre = @Genre AND Age >= @Age"

        Dim Platform As New SqlParameter("@Platform", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
        Platform.Value = ddlPlatform.SelectedItem.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Platform)

        Dim Genre As New SqlParameter("@Platform", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
        Genre.Value = ddlgenre.SelectedItem.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Genre)

        Dim Age As New SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int)
        Age.Value = txtAge.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Age)

        'Open the connection to the database
        cn.Open()
        ' Execute the sql.
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`
```

Comment: Can you state your problem clearly

Comment: Sorry I need to display the results of this query in a datalist and I dont know how, I only have ever used sqldatasource.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719635(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks that helps, how would I add parameters to this query, I have tried    myCommand = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name FROM Games Where (Platform = @Platform)", myConnection)

        Dim Platform As New SqlParameter("@Platform", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
        Platform.Value = "PS3"

Comment: Thanks to Vignesh I have been able to get this working.  I will post my compelted code after 8 hours because I am only a new memeber I have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vignesh I have been able to answer this question.

```
     Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Name, Platform, Genre, Age_Range From [Games] Where (Platform = @Platform) and (Genre = @Genre) and (Age_Range <= @Age)"

    Dim Platform As New SqlParameter("@Platform", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
    Platform.Value = ddlPlatform.SelectedItem.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Platform)

    Dim Genre As New SqlParameter("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
    Genre.Value = ddlgenre.SelectedItem.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Genre)

    Dim Age As New SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
    Age.Value = txtAge.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Age)

    cn.Open()
    Dim ds As SqlDataReader
    ds = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    MyDatalist.DataSource = ds
    MyDatalist.DataBind()
    cn.Close()
```